# Aligning underbraces in two different length terms

Tags: align, brackets, underbrace

The code I have written currently is:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:fullwavefunction}
    \psi\textbf{(r}) =\psi_s(\textbf{r}) + \phi(\textbf{r}) =\underbrace{e^{ikz}}_\text{incident wave} +  \underbrace{f(\theta,\phi)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}}_\text{scattered wave} \qquad r\gg a
\end{equation}
```

This corresponds to a TEx output of:

[image]

However I would like to alter it so that the brackets underneath my two terms are aligned with one another and the same for the texts 'incident wave' and 'scattered wave'.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

One possible solution is add to term `e^{ikz}` some strut which will make it the same depth as it has the second term, which contain a fraction. This can be done by adding `vphantom{...}` which contin an fraction with the same denominator as fraction in the second term. For example `\vphantom{1}{r}`.

For convenient writing of equation I suggest to define new command `\mystrut` as

```
\def\maystrut{\vphantom{\frac{1}{r}}}
```

and use it in your equation as is done in MWE below.

For text below i suggest to split in two lines. By this equation become more compact and to my opinion more easy to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eqn:fullwavefunction}
    \def\maystrut{\vphantom{\frac{1}{r}}}  % <---
\psi(\mathbf{r}) =\psi_s(\mathbf{r}) + \phi(\mathbf{r}) 
    = \underbrace{e^{ikz}\maystrut}_{\substack{\text{incident}\\ \text{wave}}} +
      \underbrace{f(\theta,\phi)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}}_{\substack{\text{scattered}\\ \text{wave}}},
            \quad r\gg a
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind giving a brief explanation of what you are doing here?

Comment: @PhysicsStudent, hm, I thought that the given explanation was enough, of course it is not a problem to expand it. I will do this ASAP.

Comment: @Zarko No...sigh sigh, I also I have used \vphantom :-( +1

Comment: @PhysicsStudent I suggest always after 4 years here...to put a full minimal complete code and not some snippets.

Comment: @Zarko Look the left rounded bracket with textbf it is in bold. After it is normal.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I was focused only to underbrace position ...  corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use also a `\vphantom{\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}` that has the same height of the successive term `\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}`. After in mathmode I use **\mathbf** instead of **\textbf** because the first left rounded bracket it is in bold.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\psi\mathbf{(r}) =\psi_s(\mathbf{r}) + \phi(\mathbf{r}) = \underbrace{
     \vphantom{\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}}e^{ikz}}_{\text{incident wave}}
    +  
    \underbrace{
     f(\theta,\phi)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}}_{\text{scattered wave}}, \qquad r \gg a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]

Comment: Good evening, Sebastiano! We both have a similar mindset about how to solve the OP problem ;-). of course +1

Comment: @Zarko But helloooooooo :-)....I remembered (is it correct english language? boh) of \vphantom.

Comment: My vphantom is hidden in definition os `\mastrut`, ...